# How to know who is subscribing a BehaviorSubject?

Tags: javascript, angular, behaviorsubject

I have a `BehaviorSubject` and there is a bunch of components will subscribe this subject:

```
public demoSubject:BehaviorSubject<any>;
```

When execute `this.demoSubject.next(...)`, can I know who are subscribing it and output them?

Answer (score 0):

try to binding component when subscribe

```
this.demoSubject.next({comp: this, data: {}})
```